# MySQL - Search for record within nested tables

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with two tables. The first is a hierachy of departments, whereby each record has a parent record from within the same table, and the top level has a parent_id of 0.

The second is a table of products. Each product can live anywhere in the tree of departments.

I need to be able to let people search for a product by specifying a department to search within, but for the search to look within all the sub-departments of the specified department. Can this be done in a single query?

My "Plan B" is to store a list of parent ids with each product in a new field, and search that field using a LIKE query, but that seems nasty somehow.

Dummy data:

```
id|parent_id|name  
1|0|Main 1  
2|0|Main 2  
3|0|Main 3  
4|1|Sub 1-1  
5|1|Sub 1-2  
6|1|Sub 1-3  
7|4|Sub 1-1-1  
8|4|Sub 1-1-2  
9|4|Sub 1-1-3  

id|department|product  
1|1|test product 1  
2|4|test product 2  
3|7|test product 3  

SELECT * FROM products WHERE department = 1 ; want to receive all three products  
SELECT * FROM products WHERE department = 4 ; want to receive products 2 and 3  
SELECT * FROM products WHERE department = 7 ; want to receive only product 3
```

Comment: write dummy table data and the query you tried so far.

Comment: Could you elaborate with an example of your idea and what you've tried so far?

Comment: I've added a simplified set of the dummy data. I need the queries to traverse down the tree to find records that live at a level lower than where I'm actually searching. I know I need some sort of join (if it can be done) but I don't know where to begin.

Comment: You can't do this in one query. You need either to use recursive function or to change a storage structure. Anyway I'd suggest to look how to store tree structures in relational databases.

Comment: You may be able to get some good ideas from this article: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/. In particular, if you switch from the adjacency-list model to nested sets, your query is easy.